# JavaScript - appendChild when an element starts existing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am selecting multiple elements from within a page for a Chrome Extension and some of them are not being detected.

```
var innerChat = document.querySelector('.chat-list');
```

I want to appendChild to this element, but the script moves on to editing it before it even starts existing

```
innerChat.appendChild(emoteMenuWrap);
```

which obviously results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Suppose your `innerChat` has a parent element of `chatDiv`.  `chatDiv` must exist on the page, but `innerChat` does not need to:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(callbackFunction)
const config = { subtree: true };
observer.observe(chatDiv, config);
```

When the contents of `chatDiv` change (EG when you add `innerChat` to it,) `observer` will run the callback function.

Inside the callback function is where you would do whatever thing you wanted to wait to do.

One key to success here is to pick the parent container such that there aren't other changes going on inside it that would trigger your event more than once.

Finally, you'll probably want to remove the observer inside the callback:

```
observer.disconnect();
```

NB I edited this to suggest observing the `subtree`, since you're actually adding elements, not changing exiting ones.

Answer (score 0):

Mutation observer is a good bet. For environments where this is not supported below also might do the trick since getElementsByClassName returns a live list:

```
var innerChat = document.getElementsByClassName("chat-list");
```

within your other script:

```
function process(){
   if(!innerChat.length){
       requestAnimationFrame(process);
   } else {
       innerChat[0].appendChild(emoteMenuWrap);
   }
}
requestAnimationFrame(process);
```